# ASP.NET Membership mdf to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, membership

I had membership working fine locally. But now need to deploy so created membership tables / stored procedures using the `Aspnet_regsql.exe` and changed my `web.config` to point local `sqlexpress` database instance.

My membership is still working but not using SQL Server. I went and deleted the `.mdf` file that my connection string was referring to earlier from the `APP_DATA` folder. My form authentication is still working allowing me to register new users but not using SQL Server!

What is it using?

```
<remove name="DefaultConnection"/> 
<add name="DefaultConnection" 
     connectionString="server=PC\SQLEXPRESS;Trusted_Connection=true;database=adatabase;"/>
```

My connection string looks like above. I have one more connection string below this whose value is exactly like this for now, just FYI. All the membership sections like `DefaultMembershipProvider` use `DefaultConnection` connection string.

Comment: First check your connection is happening properly or not by Con.open() in page_load event...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was looking at this table called `dbo.aspnet_Users` all this time. There is another table down below called `dbo.Users` and that is where users are getting created. So IT IS using SQL Server! The `Aspnet_regsql.exe` tool installed these `aspnet_*` tables. And it looks like the actual table where users are created is getting created afterwards. I got that from these tables' time stamps - they are over 20 mins apart.

Comment: Yep, confirmed. In production, I just used membership with correct connection string and it created required tables by itself. I had a script ready taken from local DB to run on production but no need.